# Late fusion for the CNN features

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction

I am working on early and late fusion of CNN features. I have taken features from multiple layer of CNN. For the early fusion I have captured the feature of three different layers and then horizontally concatenate them `F= [F1' F2' F3'];` For the late Fusion I was reading this [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.78.5928&rep=rep1&type=pdf). They have mentioned to do supervised learning twice. But couldn't understand the way.

For example this is the image taken from the above mentioned paper. 
The first image have three different features and for first supervised learning  the labels lets say will be 1 in 4 class image set. The output for example is [1 1 3]. Lets say the third classifier has wrong result. 
Then my question is then the  multimodal feature concatenation is like [1 1 3] with the label 1 lets say for class 1 image?

[image]

Comment: I have updated my question please le me know which part needs to explain before vote it for closing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- I might be wrong on this but this is my understanding (I am not sure about my answer)
- So let's say you have 2 classes and you have 3 different models
- So every model will output a vector of (2 x 1)
- For example

  **Model-1 : [[0.3], [0.7]]

    Model-2 : [[0.2], [0.8]]

    Model-2 : [[0.6], [0.4]]**
- Now you will concatenate (Multi-modal Features Combination) the results as follows:
     **[0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.4]**
- The above feature vector will go as input to your final supervised learner as the mentioned in the diagram the concept score goes as input to the supervised learner
- In the paper they mention about this as follows:
   **We concatenate the visual vector vi with the text vector ti.

   After feature normalization, we obtain early fusion vector ei.

   Then ei serves as the input for a SVM.**
- Now, Let's talk about the implementation of this model
- What I would do is first train Model-1 individually, train Model-2 individually, train Model-3 individually
- Now I will freeze the weights of Model-1, Model-2, Model-3 and extract the scores and combine them into the feature vector as discussed above and pass it to the final supervised learner and train it
- Think of the three Unimodal Supervised Learner as Feature Extractors and concatenate their results just like you did for early fusion and pass it to a SVM
- I would go with the class scores as feature vectors rather then the actual predictions they make which you have assumed
- Why class scores and not the actual predictions? because the class score represents the confidence of the unimodals for their prediction of the classes

Comment: Thanks for you contribution! You may want to read [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307481/bulletpoints-everywhere). Its not about you, but I think its related. In short: if you use more conventional written communication, you will get better feedback from the community. As for now, this post is super hard to read to most users.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ... But I do not agree with you... If there are guidelines on posting the answers in certain format then I don't mind following it... I think my answer is readable and helpful... And I my answers are not deviating and are specific to the questions

Comment: The only problem I have with my post that there is no code and still I formatted few lines in code and that's because stackoverflow gave me an error saying there is code in your post so format it ... That is the reason I have few lines formatted as code ... I am sorry for that  if that bugs you

Comment: Hi Jai, sorry for late reply. I am using LIBSVM library in MATLAB. how can I get score of class in that?